# angularjs select radio with conditon

Tags: angularjs, radio-button

Each radio button has one value. I want to add the values every time someone select a radio button. To select the right radio button 1 will be added and for wrong 0.5 will be subtracted. The final result will show in ov div.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('aCtrl', function($scope) {
var v= 0 ;
$scope.cal = function(){
  $scope.rv.click();
  v +=$scope.rv;
  $scope.ov = JSON.stringify(v);
};

});
```

Here is my plunker link 
http://plnkr.co/edit/onjtGkkG0FiK4dOCmJfX?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple directive for your purpose:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);


app.controller('aCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.v = 0;
});

app.directive('addOnCheck', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      addOnCheck: '='
    },
    link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
      el.on('click', function () {
        scope.$apply(function () {
          scope.addOnCheck += attrs.value;
        });
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Here is plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/6vz5VXnnub5KgFxtXUAg?p=preview

Comment: what is this $watch? would you please explain?

Comment: almost u solved it. please check again. if I select  2 right its not increasing to 2. radios are acting weird. 
plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/onjtGkkG0FiK4dOCmJfX?p=preview

Comment: as I see, you need multiple inputs with same name, value and model, because of that radios are activng weird, so you can use simple directive instead, I'll edit answer.


p.s. about $watch, here is official docs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch